# Asp.net Core Form - On Form Submit Show success/failure message

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I have created the simple chtml form in Asp.net Core view.

Now, 
1. When Form is submitted then I want to Check Validation First which is implemented using bootstrap.

2. When Validation check successful then the form should get submitted
3. Once form get submitted successfully then want to show a message that "Form has been saved successfully"

Here Issue is When I changed button type from Submit to button, and used Jquery Ajax call then I'm able to Show message on Ajax success method. 
But Bootstrap Validation doesn't work as they need form should be posted.

I expect Bootstrap Validation should work first and Once validation is successful then OnSubmit button form should be posted and once form get posted successfully, want to Show alert message.

Comment: You'll need to manually invoke the validation using the API of whatever library you're using for that. There is no official Bootstrap validation library, so it's unclear what you're actually using. Hence, it's impossible to help you further than that.

Comment: Hello Crhirs Pratt,
We have implemented the bootstrap validation by following way
https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/temp/752814?action=prism_export

Validation is working perfectly, but once form get submitted need to show success message, how can we do to show Success/Failure message after form submitted?